# Thymeleaf counter variable not incrementing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, counter, increment

I want to have a counter variable of type integer while rendering my html using thymeleaf but the counter variable is incremented unexpectedly. Below is my code. Please help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div th:with="mycounter = 0">
    <div th:with="mycounter=${mycounter + 1}">
        <span th:text="${mycounter}"></span> <!-- result: 1 -->
    </div>
    <div th:with="mycounter=${mycounter + 1}">
        <span th:text="${mycounter}"></span> <!-- result: 1 , expected: 2-->
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achiveve it using following approach:

On server-side implement a simple class called Counter:

```
public class Counter
{
    private int count;

    public Counter()
    {
        count = 0;
    }

    public Counter(int init)
    {
        count = init;
    }

    public int get()
    {
        return count;
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        count = 0;
    }

    public int incrementAndGet()
    {
        return ++count;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return ""+count;
    }
}
```

In your servlet code add:

```
context.addAttribute("counter", new Counter());
```

In your template you can use and increment it like this:

```
<div th:with="mycounter = ${counter.get()}">
    <div th:with="mycounter=${counter.incrementAndGet()}">
        <span th:text="${mycounter}"></span> <!-- result: 1 -->
    </div>
    <div th:with="mycounter=${counter.incrementAndGet()}">
        <span th:text="${mycounter}"></span> <!-- result: 2 , expected: 2-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no incrementAndGet in your class - but well... Devs have to do something, right? ;)

Comment: @jonasheinisch you're right, thanks for mentioning it. I fixed it.

Comment: How to reset counter. i.e. call `clear()` in thymeleaf?

Comment: is it thread safe?

Comment: @roberttrudel : this counter is mentioned to be used within a scope of a single request, single thread processing. So in this case it does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to variable scoping, it was raised in [Thymeleaf issue 666](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/666) with alternative approach:

> Since making variables are scoped to the element, you might not be able to get a total value using th:with, so you'll need to look elsewhere.
>
> One alternative solution would be to process the result in your controller, store the result to a model attribute, then use that result in the view. For example, in Spring:
>
> ```
> public String yourControllerEndpoint(Model model) {
>  int total = // get the total of your list
>  model.addAttribute("total", total);
>  return "your-template";
> }
> <table>
>  <!-- Your looping display code here -->
>   ...
>   <span th:text="${total}">Total will go here</span>
> </table>
> ```

Comment: ok, so can i have an `int` set on my `model` and increment that `int` variable using thymeleaf `th:with`

Comment: @Samim you can read further in link with more complex solution and comprehensive explanation

Comment: Thank you for your time. till now it has no solution, that's what we can conclude.